# Error: Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting the following error after updating Gradle to 3.3 and Android Studio version to 3.0.1

**Error**

> Error:Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1. Required
>   by:
>       project :app > com.android.support:design:25.2.0
>       project :app > com.android.support:design:25.2.0 > com.android.support:transition:25.2.0
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager.

**App Gradle Config:-**

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.cyberrafting.joinapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 9
        versionName "9"
        multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: Hello, please add more details than "Ok I have a problem thankyou". What did you do to have this error, did you tested something to fix it, what did you searched for and why it has not fixed the problem. Please help the community to help you !

Comment: @Deovrat did you get this working?

Comment: This problem is maddening.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly adding the maven did the trick

Answer (score 14):

As per https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html, make sure you're including `maven.google.com` repo

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Compile version and Build Tool version

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
```

And also all your support libraries to 27.0.2

Answer (score -1):

Copy this code in android/build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```