# Failed to Resolve: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' No Matter What I Do

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

I know, it looks like a duplicate, but none of the other solutions out there work. I just switched from Android Studio to IntelliJ IDEA (So I don't need 3,000 different IDE's), and after setting it up, I created a new project just to test everything was good. The Gradle build starts off okay but then it throws the error:

`Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3`

This is a fresh, stock, not edited `build.gradle` file.

[image: annoying message]

In the messages, it gives me the option to *`Install Repository and sync project`*, and thats where my problem begins. No matter what version the `AppCompat` library is, IntelliJ just keeps slapping this error in my face.

Any tips?

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907092/error-could-not-find-com-android-supportsupport-v427-0-1/47907207#47907207 ?

Comment: No, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because there is no `27.0.3` for that library. You probably want `27.1.0`, or perhaps `27.0.2`.

You can see the list of versions for the different artifact groups and artifacts at https://maven.google.com.

Comment: In SDK Manager, `27.1.0` is not shown there, and the same message comes even with `27.0.2`, which I also tried.

Comment: @flash76: "In SDK Manager, 27.1.0 is not shown there" -- the SDK Manager does not provide any current Gradle dependencies. The Android Repository in the SDK Manager used to be the source of libraries like `appcompat-v7`, but that changed with Android Studio 3.0. "the same message comes even with 27.0.2, which I also tried" -- then you don't have the `google()` Maven repository set up. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46024009/115145

Comment: Even with the `google()` line in the top level `build.gradle`, IDEA still fails to resolve `appcompat`.

Comment: @flash76: Try to figure out where IDEA is looking for it. Usually, as part of the not-found error, Gradle will list a set of repositories where it is searching for the artifact. Make sure the Google Maven repo is listed there.

Comment: It turns out it was a problem with the Gradle version.

Comment: @flash76 how you come to know and how did you solve that? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

**This was the my error when i tried to change my targe SDK version 23 to SDK version 26**
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.

> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:

**resolved**
@android/build.gradle :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

@app/build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "WWWWWWWWWW"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27

      ......

  //under dependicies
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0"
```

at least i solved that error that way, yes still another errors i need to solve