# React Native : Change targeted sdk version for play store upload

Tags: react-native

In Play Store I am trying to upload my app but I'm getting a warning i.e. mentioned below:

**Target API level requirements from August 2018**

**Warning**:

Your app currently targets API level 22 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance.

From August 2018, new apps must target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26).
From November 2018, app updates must target Android 8.0 (API level 26).

Comment: ...and? it is not very clear what you are trying to accomplish here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140950/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v7-no-matter-what-i-do/53749951#53749951 you try that solution too if u still needed, i just solved that way

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Open `build.gradle` under `android/app/`

find the `android { }` block

Change the following version to the below:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27
```

In the dependencies block, change the `appcompat` line to match the target version

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
```

Comment: I changed everything 26, but it simply ignores it and carries on with 27...

Comment: How do we find the numbers for the latest `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. New apps must target API level 28 now, and I don't know where to get the corresponding buildToolsVersion

Answer (score 9):

In case your current `android/app/build.gradle` has lines which look like

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
```

You will have to edit the `android/build.gradle` to include

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Although I do not know where to get the latest versions.

It would be great if someone could **edit** this to include where to get the latest version numbers

Comment: Is that buildscript block at the root of the build.gradle file?

Comment: @micahhoover [This is the file](https://github.com/samgermain/SealsSounds_ReactNative/blob/master/android/build.gradle)

Answer (score 4):

**From August 2021**, API level should be 30 or above.

I have React Native app and my `android/app/build.gradle looks` like below

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
```

Changed the android/build.gradle to have below content which worked

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change **targetVwersion** to 26 in ./android/app/build.gradle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for the maven part, mentioned by @Bodhish, I needed to do it this way:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) 
            // is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

with this piece added in addition to @albert's comment resolved for me.