# how to Change my app's target API level from 23 to 26

Tags: android, api, sdk, google-play-developer-api, android-api-levels

I have a problem when i try to upload my app to google play console and it is the API level that is must be 26 and my app is just developped with 23 version and now i don't know how to change this API version from 23 to 26 to make it works without errors.

Help me please!

Comment: `to make it works without errors` there is no universal way to do that. You just need to fix all errors.

Comment: This should help you fix some errors https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140950/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v7-no-matter-what-i-do/53749951#53749951 if u still not solve the issue, there is some answers helped me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing API level Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio)

Answer (score 11):

Steps:

1. Go to **File >Project Structure.**
2. select **App Module** in left panel
3. select **Flavour** tab from the top menu tabs
4. You  can change the **Min SDK version** (In your case change **Target SDK Version to 26**)
5. Click **Ok**

> Reference: http://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/change-api-sdk-level-android-studio.html

Comment: I don't have an App Module or see Flavour anywhere in Dolphin for Windows.

Answer (score 9):

you can change your API from build.gradle file. [image]

Answer (score 5):

In the latest version of Android Studio as of dated 2020, perform the following steps:

1. Click on Files (top left)
2. Go to Project Structure (Ctlr + Alt + Shift + S)
3. Click on modules
4. In the right pane, click on Default Config (Middle one)
5. Change Minimum SDK version
6. Apply and click OK

Done!

Answer (score 4):

For those looking at this in Android Studio 3.5.3

1. Go to **File >Project Structure**.
2. Select **Modules** on the left panel
3. Select **app** on center panel
4. On the right panel, click on **Default Config**
5. Change **Target SDK Version** to the required version

[image]

Answer (score 3):

However, there is answer that answered by friend below, just want to inform that if changing the version of the API. You also need to consider the library from the `build.gradle` app.

for example:

[image]

If you change the version, the default library file has to change to the version of your API version.

**Example**

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'` with my API version 27

Answer (score 0):

You can change minSdkVersion from 23 to 26,
under "Gradle Scripts>>build.gradle(Module:app)".then sync