# Change your app's target API level to at least 26

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-api-levels

When I raise my app on Google play
This shows me the problem

Your app currently targets API level 25 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 26

- Note I use Unity

You have updated sdk the latest version

Please help how I change API level to at least 26
in Unity

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1571926/view.html) can help? You can find the document about setting up Android environment [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Change my app's target API level from 23 to 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404548/how-to-change-my-apps-target-api-level-from-23-to-26)

Comment: Meet Google Play's target API level requirement. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

Just open your build.gradle(Module: app) and change your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion 26 or more than 26. [image]

Comment: Note I use Unity

Answer (score 0):

Target API level is a setting in PlayerSetting. Just change it there

[image]

Comment: What version number are you using?

Comment: I have 25 apl Unity 5.6.4f1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

- go to **build.gradle** file in your project
- look for **defaultTargetSdkVersion** & **defaultCompileSdkVersion**
- then change value to **26**
  [image]