# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v7:27.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

my grade: I do not know what should change, in addition these errors are generated and I have already updated the files from compile to implementation.

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Configuration 'debugCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'debugImplementation' and 'debugApi'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
  }

 dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

apply plugin: 'hugo'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.code44.finance'
    targetSdkVersion 27
    minSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 81
    versionName '0.18.3'
    buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_LOCAL_SERVER", "true"
    buildConfigField "String", "LOCAL_SERVER_IP", "\"192.168.0.7\""
    buildConfigField "long", "BUILD_TIME", "" + buildTime() + "L"
  }
   lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
   compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }
   buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-debug'
    }
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
    }
   }
   sourceSets {
    androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
  }
  signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
     }
   }
 }

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
implementation project(path: ':common')
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library- 
 circular:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.7.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
compileOnly 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
implementation 'org.beanshell:bsh-core:2.0b4'
implementation 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.4'
implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.4.0'
implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
implementation 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:3.1.0'
implementation project(':common')
implementation 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.1.13'
implementation(name: 'hellocharts-library-1.3', ext: 'aar')
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.0.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2'
}

def buildTime() {
return System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

repositories

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
   }
  }

   allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
     }
   }
}
```

if you want to help me compile I would appreciate sending the full project link
[project link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10NWNPtNAEP8NhjdILEz8iI1qrT_PvKJ3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907092/error-could-not-find-com-android-supportsupport-v427-0-1/47907207#47907207

Comment: There's a mismatch between the version you want to use and buildToolsVersion

Answer (score 1):

I Hope this will work for you

Add this in project gradle file

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple it says itself.

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v7:27.1.1

It is not an dependency available. Perhaps you are giving wrong dependency. **Most probably you need appCompactv7** use

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
```

or this if you are pointing to this.

```
com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `com.android.support:support-v7:27.1.1` into `com.android.support:design:27.1.1` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }
```