# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-studio-3.0

I'm new in android ,install the android studio 3.2.1 and try to create new project,but get this error:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

my project gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and app gradle is :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.brazzaqi.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

how can i solve that error?thanks.

Comment: Please, show dependencies ...

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50103620/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportsupport-v727-1-1?rq=1)?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta please review my question'

Comment: @Piyush yes my friend

Comment: Did you see all related questions. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Failed+to+resolve:+com.android.support:appcompat+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN820IN821&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHwa6jwPbeAhVIvY8KHd6zAG4QrQIoBDAAegQICRAM&biw=1920&bih=889

Comment: @Khemraj no ,but check that now

Comment: Check offline mode should be disabled. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712025/how-to-disable-gradle-offline-mode-in-android-studio

Comment: check whether you have installed necessary build tools version from sdk manager.

Comment: @Simi did you check this `Preferences -> Gradle -> Global Gradle Settings -> Offline work` offline work is enabled or not?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed offline work is disable

Comment: Would you please check out the `gradle-wrapper.propertise` which version of gradle version you have used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.brazzaqi.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}    
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: connection time out error,can you say me what happen?

Comment: so get error Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Comment: for now which error you are facing after compile to implementation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2448775/simi use compileSdkVersion 27 it will works

Comment: @AbhinavGupta my friend,this solution did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
 }}
```

Comment: so get error Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Comment: Then try to upgrade your **compileSdkVersion 27** to **compileSdkVersion 28** and try again.!

Comment: Don't forget to change dependency version also from 27 to 28.